# What is the easiest way to do filtered replication to another SQL Server 2012 database with the exact same schema?

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

I need to start a filtered replication of a SQL Server 2012 database for a company subsidiary that contains only a subset of records related to that subsidiary (using only row filters).  This is in preparation for a cutover where the application will THEN be pointed to the new database.  The new database needs to be in the same instance; the difference is only the database name.

To avoid application change, we need to keep the 2 database schema exactly the same (table definition, auto-increment primary keys, default values, indexes, etc).

The database is quite simple (no triggers, no stored procedure).  Changes to the database by the application is limited to transactional insert, update, delete, but relies heavily on default values and auto-increment on the primary key fields.

Currently, the replicated database can be in "read only" mode since for now it only serves as the data repository prior to the cutover.

My main concerns are:

- the auto-increment primary key on the subscriber database: whether publishing a subset of rows (non-contiguous primary key) will cause an issue.
- how to identify the record to be published when the criteria is in another table that is *not* part of the insert/update.

What is the easiest way to do this, using any available feature of Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Comment: sql server 2012 is very very old, maybe you should think about an upgrade

Comment: @nbk I agree.  Upgrade is in the pipeline.  Is there an easier solution with SQL Server 2016 and up?  I'm reading up on [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2016) which seems will do what I need, just need to watch for the autoincrement on the subscriber database.  What do you think?  I was also thinking of using log shipping, is there such a thing as "*filtered* log shipping"?  I doubt it but thought it doesn't hurt to ask.